# Error when I try to create a new account with "deis register" command

Tags: amazon-ec2, proxy, deis

I've a fresh install of Deis on AWS but I get this error when I try to register an user:
http://deis.XXXX.com does not appear to be a valid Deis controller.

Also, when I try to make a curl to the ELB or any node it return a timeout, but I think that it's a normal behaviour due to the security group configutarion.
It could be a proxy configuration error? Because when I installed Deis I got this error:

Enabling proxy protocol failed, please enable proxy protocol manually after finishing your deis cluster installation.

And I enabled it manually with:
deisctl config router set proxyProtocol=1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have enabled proxyProtocol on the router you should be able to run `deisctl install platform` without issues.

Is that not the case?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I hadn't registered my deis cluster domain with global dns - i.e., I had only added it to a Route 53 hosted zone that wasn't actually public.

I fixed it by adding an `A ALIAS` record in Route 53 pointing a wildcard sub-domain under my existing domain to the `deiswebelb` host.

Name:
`*.apps.example.com`

Type: `A`

Value: `ALIAS dualstack.deis-deiswebelb-1abcdefghijkl-1234567890.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`